# Rotating earth around sun in android?

Tags: android, rotation

I am developing an android app where I have two images named earth and sun. I want to rotate the earth around the sun depending upon the user's touch event. That means the user should rotate the earth image. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Find some resources (books, online tutorials, etc.) that will teach you about graphics programming on Android.
2. Take your first stab at writing the code for this project yourself.
3. If you get stuck, post a question that displays the code you have written, and describe the issue you are having with that code.